# How to get query result in same order as given in clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below, id being the primary key

```
      ID Name
      1  a
      2  b
      3  c
      4  d
      5  e
```

and have a query like below. This query is created in a php file from user input choices.

```
    select name from table where id in (1,5,3)
```

I get the result ("a", "c", "e") which I guess is normal because of the default primary key sort order. However I want result to be ordered in the same sequence as the "in" clause. So I want returned value to be ("a", "e", "c"). Is there any way to get it in mysql.

Comment: One way you can use union to join result the order selected from UI end

Comment: Yes jensgram. It is a dup. The answer from Raging Bull is also same as yours over there. I am curious why I didn't find it earlier, may be because all related keywords "mysql", "sort", "order", "in" are very generic. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `FIELD()`:

```
select name from TableName where id in (1,5,3)
ORDER BY field(id,1,5,3)
```

Result:

```
NAME
a
e
c
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fcc9/3).

Comment: I've never had to use something like that and I did't know that kind of sort with the field operator. Very useful.

Comment: This is brilliant. I never really expected it to be so easy. Thanks so much.

Comment: Not working with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CASE operator to specify the order:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9)
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 3 THEN 1
                 WHEN 6 THEN 2
                 WHEN 1 THEN 3
                 WHEN 8 THEN 4
                 WHEN 9 THEN 5
         END
```

in php u can do it like :

```
<?php

$my_array =  array (3,6,1,8,9) ;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table  WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9)';

$sql .= "\nORDER BY CASE id\n";
foreach($my_array as $k => $v){
    $sql .= 'WHEN ' . $v . ' THEN ' . $k . "\n";
}
$sql .= 'END ';

echo $sql;

?>
```